# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type in ANGULAR

Tags: angular

I am Facing Error While Updating the Listed Form, ReactForm Here is the Code I have Attached Please Help Me out on this... Thanks in Advance
My Code::

```
import { CommonService } from './../common.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-resturant',
  templateUrl: './update-resturant.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-resturant.component.css']
})
export class UpdateResturantComponent implements OnInit {
  alert : Boolean = false;
  updateResto = new FormGroup({
    Name: new FormControl(''),
    Email: new FormControl('')
  })

  constructor(private resto:CommonService, private router: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.resto.getCurrentData(this.router.snapshot.params.id).subscribe((result)=> {
      console.log(result)
      this.updateResto = new FormGroup({
        Name: new FormControl(result['Name']),
        Email: new FormControl(result['Email'])
    })
  }
  }
```

Error::

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"Email"' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
Property 'Email' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Service Code::

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonService {
URL= "http://localhost:3000/list"

  constructor(private _http:HttpClient) { }
  getRestoList(){
    return this._http.get(this.URL)
  }

  addResto(data: any){
    return this._http.post(this.URL, data);
  }

  // deleteCurrentData(id: any){
  //   return this._http.delete(`${this.URL}/${id}`)
  // }

  getCurrentData(id: number){
    return this._http.get(`${this.URL}/${id}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: You should just update the `this.updateResto` elems values but rather re-creating them.

Comment: Check the following [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/O57dtVOqWHvuYmI4)

Comment: By Updating My Code Into This as You Mentioned, IT is Being Compiled But Not Taking The Backend Value Into The Form, It is Just Showing Oject Object On the Bar
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.resto.getCurrentData(this.router.snapshot.params.id).subscribe((result)=> {
      console.log(result)
      this.updateResto.controls['Name'].setValue(result),
      this.updateResto.controls['Email'].setValue(result)
    })
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to re-create the **FormGroup** but rather just update the **FormControl** values. Checkout [Reactive Form Guides](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.resto.getCurrentData(this.router.snapshot.params.id).subscribe((result)=> {
      this.updateResto.controls['Name'].setValue(result['Name']);
      this.updateResto.controls['Email'].setValue(result['Email']);

      // OR you can update them all at once
      this.updateResto.setValue({
        Name: result['Name'],
        Email: result['Email']
    })
  }
```

Please see the following [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/O57dtVOqWHvuYmI4) for your reference.

Comment: Thank You, Sir, This Solved My Error... :) Thanks For Your Quick Response Sir

Answer (score 0):

update: 
First of all assign your Form Group in OnInit:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.updateResto = new FormGroup({
    // name form controls in lowerCamelCase
    name: new FormControl(''),
    email: new FormControl(''),
  });

  // then make a query to your backend API
  this.resto.getCurrentData(this.router.snapshot.params.id).subscribe((result)=> {
      // I just gave wrong answer, since formGroup.value's are readonly properties
      // to update values use formGroup.patchValue():
      this.updateResto.patchValue({
        name: result.whatevervalue,
        email: result.whatevervalue2
      });
  })
}
```

And in top of class you just define variable updateResto:

```
// ! is for strict mode, typescript throws errors that your variable was not defined
updateResto!: FormGroup;
```

According to your code, when you enter your component, you already created FormGroup, and when your service returns value, you trying to assign new form group

Comment: Error: src/app/update-resturant/update-resturant.component.ts:23:44 - error TS2339: Property 'Name' does not exist on type 'Object'.

23       this.updateResto.value.Name = result.Name;
                                              ~~~~
src/app/update-resturant/update-resturant.component.ts:24:45 - error TS2339: Property 'Email' does not exist on type 'Object'.

24       this.updateResto.value.Email = result.Email;

Comment: Still Facing the Same Error Sir.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: Updated My Code as you suggested sir, but still facing the same error

Comment: Error: src/app/update-resturant/update-resturant.component.ts:25:22 - error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Object'.

25         name: result.name,
                        ~~~~
src/app/update-resturant/update-resturant.component.ts:26:23 - error TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'Object'.

26         email: result.email